# How lockscreen applications disable Home and RecentApps buttons in tablets?

Tags: android

Please don't duplicate this question. I'm bored searching internet for finding a solution. I saw many screen lockers that disable home and recent apps in all phones  ,tablets and new androids versions (5.0.2 for example). I'm designing a screen locker and I want to disable that buttons in every phone and tablet. I used Android-HomeKey-Locker to lock that buttons, but it does not work on android 4.4.2 and newer versions. how these applications do that? please don't say "its not possible" because many other applications do that in every android version.

I used this: https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker

Comment: Those apps works by becoming the default launcher app.

Comment: thanks, but it is not good idea for a locker application. I found that those apps use Views of type TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question. I used Views and it solved my problem:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    this.winManager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    this.wrapperView = new RelativeLayout(getBaseContext());
    getWindow().setAttributes(localLayoutParams);
    View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_lockscreen, this.wrapperView);
    this.winManager.addView(this.wrapperView, localLayoutParams);
```